# Shortening Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

For [my project](http://ambo100.com/salmoneus/database/itemdb.html) i've been working on. I have a piece of Javascript code that inserts text into an input element with it's label has been double clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name-label').dblclick(function(){
        $("#name").val('[b][color="#FF0000"]Please Submit![/color][/b]');
    });
});
```

But I would like this code to work with multiple fields without copying and pasting the code over and over again. I would like the text inserted to stay the same.

Here are labels and input ID's I would like to use:

**Label / Input**

```
name-label / name
image-label / image
quest-label / quest
price-label / price
ge-label / ge
halch-label / halch
lalch-label / lalch
details-label / details
examine-label / examine
location-label / location
stats-label / stats
keywords-label / keywords
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label[id$="label"]').dblclick(function(){
        $('#' + this.id.split('-')[0]).val('[b][color="#FF0000"]Please Submit![/color][/b]');
    });
});
```

1 - Bind to all elements with IDs [ending with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) 'label'.

2 - Since you follow the same convention for your ID attributes, find the correct element by extracting the first word from the clicked ID, and prepend a '#' to form an ID selector.

Comment: Just one more thing. Can you make it so it excludes input fields with dropdowns?

Comment: You mean *if it is a `<select>`, do nothing?*

Answer (score 0):

create a map of element-id/object combination and attach the function ptr to it.

Answer (score 0):

This code takes the clicked label, and uses the `for` attribute to find the appropriate `<input>` field to populate.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("label").dblclick(function () {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).val('[b][color="#FF0000"]Please Submit![/color][/b]');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
function insertSubmitString(label_id, id) {
    $('#' + label_id).dblclick(function(){
        $('#' + id).val('[b][color="#FF0000"]Please Submit![/color][/b]');
    });
};

function insertAllSubmitStrings() {
  insertSubmitString('name-label', 'name');
  insertSubmitString('image-label', 'image');
  insertSubmitString('quest-label', 'quest');
  // and so on
};

$(document).ready(insertAllSubmitStrings());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label').dblclick(function(){
        var inp = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
        $("#"+inp[0]).val('[b][color="#FF0000"]Please Submit![/color][/b]');
    });
});
```